# Why do I get a NullPointerException?

Tags: apex, null-pointer

The below code throws a NullPointerException at this line:

```
WClass W = new WClass(con); WC.add(W);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
public class WrapperClassExample{
  public List<WClass> WC{get;set;}
  public WrapperClassExample()
  {
     List<WClass> c = new List<WClass>();
     List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>([select id, name,Email from Contact]);
     system.debug(con);
       WClass W = new WClass(con);
       WC.add(W);
  }
  public class WClass{
      public boolean checkBox{get;set;}
      public list<contact> contacts{get;set;}
      public String  str{get;set;}
      public WClass(){}
      public WClass(List<Contact> c){
          this.checkBox = false;
          this.contacts = c;

      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because you are referencing field, that is not yet instantiated thus is `null` here.

```
WC.add(W);
```

you need to create instance for `public List<WClass> WC{get;set;}` field before adding to it element.

```
public class WrapperClassExample{
  public List<WClass> WC{get;set;}
  public WrapperClassExample()
  {
     WC = new List<WClass>(); // this fixes null pointer exception
     List<WClass> c = new List<WClass>();
     List<Contact> con = new List<Contact>([select id, name,Email from Contact]);
     system.debug(con);
       WClass W = new WClass(con);
       WC.add(W);
  }
  public class WClass{
      public boolean checkBox{get;set;}
      public list<contact> contacts{get;set;}
      public String  str{get;set;}
      public WClass(){}
      public WClass(List<Contact> c){
          this.checkBox = false;
          this.contacts = c;

      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a brief overview of what a NPE *is*, since the OP's code demonstrates a basic lack of understanding of the general problem.